# Scroll offscreen view contained in AppBarLayout

Tags: android, material-design, android-design-library, androiddesignsupport

I am testing the new Support Design Library and I am facing the following problem.

When scrolling to the top the `toolbar` and `imageView` views collapse as they are supposed to be but I'd like to scroll the CustomViewPager offscreen too.

I've written a CustomBehavior for CustomViewPager but it doesn't seems to be called, maybe because it is inside the appbar. I can't put it outside the AppBarLayout otherwise will be truncated.
I've managed to hide the CustomViewPager but when it happen the view jumps and doesn't look good hence why I want to scroll it offscreen.

Any suggestion?

```
    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
        app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp">
    <com.views.NetworkImageViewExt
        android:id="@+id/imageViewPostDebate"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/holding_image_post_dashboard"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        />

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageViewVideoIcon"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:src="@drawable/play_video"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            />
    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    <com.views.CustomViewPager
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:id="@+id/viewPager"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/viewpager_scrolling_view_behavior"
       />
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<com.views.FixedRecyclerView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/comments_recycle_view"
    android:background="@color/white"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    />

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/post_coordinator_layout"
    android:id="@+id/add_comment"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"
    android:src="@drawable/share_icon_xxhdpi"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/view_margin_10"
    android:clickable="true"/>
```

```
public class CustomViewPagerBehaviour extends CoordinatorLayout.Behavior<CustomViewPager> {

public CustomViewPagerBehaviour(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super();
}

@Override
public boolean layoutDependsOn(CoordinatorLayout parent, CustomViewPager child, View dependency) {
    return dependency instanceof FixedRecyclerView || dependency instanceof CollapsingToolbarLayout ||
            dependency instanceof AppBarLayout;
}

@Override
public boolean onDependentViewChanged(CoordinatorLayout parent, CustomViewPager child, View dependency) {
    if(translationY < -1000){
        child.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }else
    {
        child.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    return true;
}
```

}

Comment: Use getBottom() instead of translationY

Comment: dependency.getBottom()? The problem is that to catch the CustomBehavior the CustomViewPager must be outside AppBarLayout.This solution doesn't work for me.